# how to list image tags using aws cli on windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

Im trying to list the image tags from ECR repo using below command on windows

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat   | jq '.imageIds   | map (.imageTag)  | sort | .[]'   | sort -r   | head -1
```

I installed jq utility , however , it says `'map' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

i tried lot finding map utility for windows but did not get . how can I make this entire command work on windows ? it worked perfectly on linux.

any workaround ?
do we have any equivalent command on windows ? please suggest

**UPDATE 1**

**on windows**

```
C:\Users\ik\Downloads>aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat   | jq '.imageIds   | map (.imageTag)  | sort | .[]'   | sort -r   | head -1
'map' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\ik\Downloads>
```

**on linux**

```
root@CSX-Ik:~# aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat | jq '.imageIds | map (.imageTag)|sort|.[]' | sort -r | head -1
"19617.1"
root@CSX-Ik:~#
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
PS C:\Users\ik\Downloads> aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:5fd06c0b6c6349324343232432429e8bf6b1ce62d810c2eef1eca",
            "imageTag": "20230421.001"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:d7a28e9e62c5465465465469080eeae6a8308c99ec032a845119202f6d427ef8",
            "imageTag": "33345.1"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:681ae17a52a4c673cc8c62d50823432432432432432432497789879c37a4",
            "imageTag": "3445.2"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:ff7090d214ac72334323243209809809803e8af",
            "imageTag": "33456.1"
        }
}
]
}
```

after putting map equivalent

```
C:\Users\ik\Downloads>aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat   | jq '.imageIds   | [.[]   | .imageTag]   | sort | .[]'   | sort -r   | head -1
'[.[]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\ik\Downloads>
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat` as well as the desired result? Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide what I asked

Comment: [`jq` docs](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#map(x),map_values(x)) state _"`map(x)` is equivalent to `[.[] | x]`"_.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Paolo : please see update 2

Comment: @rickhg12hs , please see update 2

Comment: What is the output of `jq --version`?  There is a spurious `}` in the output of `aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat`.  Typo?

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is an adequate [`--query`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/list-images.html) string for `aws ecr list-images ...` that would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: jq version is : jq-1.6

Comment: I don't have an explanation for your `jq` behavior on Windows.  I also don't run Windows so I can't reproduce your test/issue.  Hopefully a Windows user will have some helpful suggestions.

Comment: You cannot use `'` on Windows, you have to use `"`. Single quotes do not denote a single string argument the same way they do in Linux shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the command on windows

For Windows :

```
powershell.exe aws ecr list-images --repository-name <repo-name> | jq '.imageIds | map (.imageTag) | sort | reverse | first'"
```

same is mentioned here

https://eduwebmonster.com/how-to-list-aws-ecr-images-with-latest-tag-on-windows-and-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `--query` parameter of AWS cli. So this is what you need:

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name plat --query 'imageIds[].imageTag' --output text
```